# How to disconnect client from the server on button click event using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, visual-studio-2008, client-server

I am developing a client server application using socket programming.
i have connect and disconnect button on client side in which one is enable at same time.
i have successfully done code on connect button.

Now, my requirement is when i press disconnect button it breaks connection from the server 
and then establish a connection when connect button is press.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) class you can simply use the `Close` method.  This applies to the standard [`C# Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) class, and most others so it should be what you require.

```
public void btnCloseConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    yourConnectionObject.Close();
}
```

From MSDN:

> Based on the LingerState property, the TCP connection may stay open
>   for some time after the Close method is called when data remains to be
>   sent. There is no notification provided when the underlying connection
>   has completed closing.

Comment: yeah darren i am using tcpclient i have done this but it's not working

Comment: @MahmoodKhan - from MSDN it states that connection maybe lingering, which is dictated by the `LingerState` property, you will just have to wait until the object is disposed of by the CLR and it will be closed.  If you're invoking the `Close` method, the framework will take care of it for you.